# Cylindrical coordinates in quotient of symmetric space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, symmetric-spaces

I am interested in the following situation. Suppose $G/K$ is a symmetric space of non-compact type and $\alpha$ is the axis of a hyperbolic isometry. I am interested in computing the Hessian of the function $z\mapsto d^2(\alpha,z)$.

Here is an example of this situation.

Let $(C,\sigma)$ be the quotient $\mathbb{H}/\langle z\mapsto \lambda^2 z\rangle$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane equipped with its hyperbolic metric $dz^2/|\Im z|^2$. Let $\gamma$ denote the core geodesic. If we take the region between $|z|=1$ and $|z|=|\lambda|^2$ to be a fundamental domain for $C$ in $\mathbb{H}$, we have orthonormal coordinates $$\{\xi_1,\xi_2\} = \{(\sin \theta)^{-1}\partial/\partial \theta, (r\sin \theta)^{-1}\partial/\partial r\}$$ One can then compute $$\textrm{Hess}d^2(\gamma,\cdot) = 2d\xi_1\otimes d\xi_1 + 2d(\gamma,\cdot)\tanh d(\gamma,\cdot)d\xi_2\otimes d\xi_2$$ Lifting to the universal cover we get the desired Hessian.

I am looking to do some similar. The missing ingredient is a nice set of orthonormal coordinates on $\langle \alpha \rangle \backslash G/K$. Is there a source where such coordinates are constructed?